# VBScript: Reminder for office workers and personal use

Tags: vbscript

My program asks the user for any events that he will be having later on (eg. meeting/special lunch event/submit report/pay bills/birthday) and will remind the user when the time comes.

Here is my code:

```
Dim remind
re=MsgBox("Do you want me to remind you anything later on?", vbYesNo, "Reminder")
If re=6 then call main

Sub main
    ' Ask for the time that the user wanted to be reminded
    remind=InputBox("At what time?" & vbNewLine & 
                    "Please use this format {H:MM:SS AM/PM}" & vbNewLine &
                    "Note: H is in 12h format")

    ' Description eg. "Lunch with boss"
    reminder=InputBox("Any discription you want to add in?")

    Do Until check=remind
        check=Time
        If check=remind Then MsgBox reminder
    Loop
End Sub
```

For example, I put in `12:30:00 PM` and `Lunch with boss`. Even when the time comes nothing happens, no popup. And when I check my TaskManager it is still running.

I'm using wscript.exe to run this script. It's the `do until check=remind` part that doesn't work. If I put `do until check="12:30:00 PM"` then it will work.

PS: I know we can use the Microsoft Outlook for the reminder or even use our phones. But this is well suited for workers that are 24h infront of the computer and lazy to use their phones and update their outlook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Convert to Date data type

The issue seems to be that the `remind` variable is a [String](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9e7a57cf%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) data type, and the `check` variable is a [Date](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9e7a57cf%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) data type.  When you try to compare them, they'll always fail to be equal, even if the actual date inside both types is the same.

You can solve the problem by using the [CDate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dt118h2%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function to convert `remind` to a Date before entering the loop.

```vb
remind = CDate(remind)
```

### Validation

Because you're now using CDate to convert the user's input, if they make a typo and enter an invalid date, its going to bring up an error box and end the program.  You may want to use [IsDate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/48y0723t%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to ensure it is a valid time before converting it, then gracefully ask the user to enter the time again if they made a typo.

### CPU Usage

Your loop will sit there taking up 100% CPU usage of one core of the machine its running on.  This can slow down your user's computer, among other side effects.

To fix this issue, you want to slow down the loop, such that its only checking a few times a second, rather than a few hundred times a second.  Insert this statement inside the loop to have it sleep for 500 milliseconds before trying again.

```vb
WScript.Sleep 500
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. My input is actually 12:30:00 PM not {12:30:00 PM}. The curly brackets is just to indicate my input within them. Anyways when i excute the program why it doesn't works while yours works?

Comment: I just did a cut and paste into visual studio 2012, and made very minor changes to get it to compile;  What are you running it under?

Comment: I'm using wscript.exe. It's the (do until check=remind) part that doesn't works. If i put it like (do until check="12:30:00 PM") then it will works. Any comments about it?

Comment: I've updated my answer in light of the additional information you provided.  It worked when I originally tested it because I was running it as full Visual Basic, not as VBScript, and they act differently for that type of comparison.  I've tested it using wscript and it works fine with the modifications I suggested.

Comment: Thank you so much Curtis! It works so well now. Appereciate your time and your shared knowledge :)